# How do I say "my wife baked these for me"?

Tags: translation

How do I say "my wife baked these for me", where "these" can be cookies, pie, etc? In English I can use "make" or "bake" as the verb. Would I use 烘? When referencing one's own wife, is 太太 appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

You can say

我太太为我烘烤了这些

Emphasizing on my wife. Usually, you can just use 烤 and leave the 烘. Actually my wife have never said 烘 when it comes to baking

Answer (score 3):

**Oral:**

1.我老婆为我做的.
2.我妻子给我烤的.

做 means make ,老婆 or 妻子 means wife.    为 means for     给  means for.

**rustic**

1.我家那人给我做的.
1.我家那口子给我做的.

somebody's 家那人 or somebody's 家那口子 means  wife.

**cultured**

1.我太太为我烘烤的.

太太:wife.

**written:**

1.我妻子为我做的.

2.我妻子为我烘烤的.

**conservative nerd**

1.内人炙之.

2.此鄙人贱内为在下烘烤.
内人 means wife.   为 means make. 之 means these or those. 炙:bake

鄙人 means  I    .贱内 means wife . 此:  this  在下 means  I (me).

Comment: A nerd like this would be impossible to have a wife..

Comment: @WangDingwei :)   How true the truth is.

Comment: LOL for the conservative nerd

Comment: Very entertaining

Answer (score 2):

You might say "这(些)是我太太给(为)我烤的" or "我太太烤的", but had better not just say "我太太为我烤了这些" in most situation. For "bake", "烤" and "做" are both okay. In a polite way, "Wife" can be translated as "太太" or "爱人".

Word order is the biggest difference between English and Chinese. Most of the time "这些" should come first in Chinese sentences. More colloquially, "这些" can be abbreviated to "这" and "给" can replace "为". You can even omit "这些" if you were pointing at the bread when you said the sentence.

There're no grammatical mistakes in "我太太为我烤了这些", but Chinese people hardly speak like that because this sentence doesn't seem complete and the word order seems a little strange (an awkward expression/translation). Here's a way to make it better —— "我太太为我烤了这些面包/饼干". The sentence can be regarded complete when you add the specific thing and doesn't seem so strange any more.

In general, I recommend you use "这(些)是我太太给(为)我烤的".

Answer (score 0):

You can say:这是我妻子为我做的。
And when referencing one's wife,you could say:你老婆，你妻子 or 你爱人，but 你老婆 is common.